# Application crash during createVideoThumbnail

Tags: android, file, listview, explorer

currently I'm using `listview` to create a file explorer with video thumbnail. However the app crash when `createVideoThumbnail`, after removing the code the app works just fine. Below is the snippet of the part which `createVideoThumbnail`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                File file = files[i];

                if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                    path.add(file.getPath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                    } else {
                        item.add(file.getName());
                    Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getPath(),
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                    rowImage.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                    }
                }
            }
```

below is the whole class source code

```
public class Video extends ListActivity {
    List<String> item = null;
    List<String> path = null;
    String root;
    TextView myPath;
    int visibility;
    String VideoPath;
    ListView list;
    VideoView VideoView;
    View v;
    File f;
    Button home;
    Button exit;
    ImageView rowImage;
    MediaController mController;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);
        myPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);
        VideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        rowImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rowimage);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        getDir(root);

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getDir(root);
            }
        });
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    void getDir(String dirPath) {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if (!dirPath.equals(root)) {
            item.add("/BACK");
            path.add(f.getParent());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                } else {
                    item.add(file.getName());
                Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(file.getPath(),
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
                rowImage.setImageBitmap(bMap);
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.rowtext, item);

        Collections.sort(path);
        Collections.sort(item);

        setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        File file = new File(path.get(position));

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (file.canRead()) {
                getDir(path.get(position));
            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            }
        } else {
            if (visibility == 0) {
                VideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                visibility = 1;
                VideoPath = file.getPath();

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(VideoPath);
                VideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
                list.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mController = new MediaController(this);
                VideoView.setMediaController(mController);
                VideoView.start();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String intentAction = intent.getAction();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(intentAction) && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
                    VideoPath = intent.getDataString();
                }

            } else if (visibility == 1) {
                VideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                visibility = 0;
                VideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (visibility == 1) {
            VideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            VideoView.stopPlayback();
            visibility = 0;
        } else if (f.getPath().equals(root)) {
            finish();
        } else {
            getDir(f.getParent());
        }
    }
}
```

below is the logcat

```
12-16 18:28:18.449: D/SurfaceView(7333): get context in surfaceview init
12-16 18:28:21.959: D/AndroidRuntime(7333): Shutting down VM
12-16 18:28:21.959: W/dalvikvm(7333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412a8930)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at com.myapp.MyCarousel.Video.getDir(Video.java:135)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at com.myapp.MyCarousel.Video.onListItemClick(Video.java:188)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onKeyUp(AbsListView.java:2890)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.widget.ListView.commonKey(ListView.java:2258)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.widget.ListView.onKeyUp(ListView.java:2113)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2865)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1354)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchKeyEvent(ListView.java:2088)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2394)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3703)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2820)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-16 18:28:21.969: E/AndroidRuntime(7333):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone has any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Show the logcat with the crash error.

Comment: Your app crash because on your method onListItemClick() at the line 139 you take a NullPointerExeption.

Comment: It seems an error of getting null directory path

Comment: Try to print path.get(position) before call getDir() in your listener. What is the result ?

Comment: it returns "/storage/emulated/0/Video"